# Shock on every metal part of the apartment

Tags: electrical

The main breaker in the electrical room for an apartment Is off. Not power into the panel breaker. When the people touch metal knob door or other metal part  into the apartment , even  the contact with corners of the walls  cause a zip (shock) .that zip disappear after the first contact and then suddenly happen again.
What could be the cause when everything Is disconnected from electrical room.? Also a test disconnecting the power and the  neutral wire that feed that apartment was made and still shock occur.
None of the other units beside that apartment feel that shock.

Comment: What's the relative humidity in that apartment? Are the floors hardwood/tile, or carpeted?

Comment: Humidity set 45. Floor is New tile ceramic floor

Comment: Does this happen while wearing shoes? Also, what are the materials of the doors where the doorknob shocks you: wood / metal / fiberglass? You indicate new ceramic floors, did this occur before the floors were installed? Is there an in-floor heating system? What material is on the corners of the walls where you get shocked -- drywall?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You describe a shock when you touch a metal object. If you immediately touch the same object again, do you get another shock? If not, then you're dealing with (annoying but harmless) static. If so, then you're dealing with (possibly dangerous) power leakage.

Comment: It happens wearing shoes. Doorknob is metal, not floor heating system, corner of walls is drywall but there are corner bit metals. Walls are covered and painted.

Comment: After you touch the metal and get the initial shock then you touch it again and dissappear. But again walk around comeback and happens again, It is when the skin is near the metal, once you touched tightly the shock dissappear dont feel it. But it is crazy everywhere. Everytime.

Comment: If the doors themselves are made of wood and you get shocked touching the door knob while wearing shoes, then my best guess is that you somehow manage to build up a lot of static electricity while walking around your apartment, but not other people's apartments--there is not a great mechanism of conducting electricity from another source on a doorknob on a wooden door or through shoes with synthetic soles. Therefore, the shock is most likely from static potential created by you moving (e.g. rubbing a balloon in your hair). You may want to call in an electrician to be on the safe side though.

Answer (score 2):

### This sounds like a rather...static-y problem

Because the shocks take time to come back after they happen (instead of happening repeatedly every time you touch metal), this is most likely an issue with *static electricity* buildup, which can be due to a variety of factors, such as clothing and building materials used, ambient relative humidity, and such.  It's not a sign of electrical trouble, at least, though!

Answer (score 0):

Immediately call a licensed professional to look at the problem.  I would also call your electricity providing utility.